# replacing/ignoring punctuation in string java

Tags: java, arrays, string, replace

so basically for my uni work i have to create an applet that gives a word pattern for a particular sentence, ie 'i am a man' would give 2, 1, 1, because there are 2 1 letter words, 1 2 letter word and 1 3 letter word. the harder part (atleast for me) is that i have to exclude all punctuation for example i, i would come out as 2 as the comma is, meant to be, excluded as a character.

My lecturer said this bit of code should work 
`str = str.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "");` 
but the problem is i dont know how to intergrate it into my applet, spent ages looking at it. this is basically the last part of the applet (this plus a graph). hopefully you understand what i mean, if you can help me out it would be much appreciated. also on a side note i haven't actually been taught str.replace yet.

This is what i have so far (hopefully ive put this in correctly)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class clarke_j_reass  extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
    Button pr_input1, pr_input2;

    Label pr_label;
    TextField pr_text;
    String pr_name;

    public void init()

    {
        pr_input1 = new Button("Analyze");
        pr_input2 = new Button("Reset");
        add(pr_input1);
        add(pr_input2);
        pr_input1.addActionListener(this);
        pr_input2.addActionListener(this);
        //add the buttons with action listeners
        pr_label = new Label("Word Pattern");
        add(pr_label);
        pr_text = new TextField();
        add(pr_text);
        pr_text.addActionListener(this);
        //add text field
    }    
    public void start()
    {           
        pr_name="";
            setSize(400,400);
            setBackground(Color.gray);
        pr_text.setBackground(Color.white);      
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){


    pr_name = e.getActionCommand();
    repaint();
        if(e.getSource() == pr_input1)
            pr_name = pr_text.getText();
        else
            if(e.getSource() == pr_input2)
            {   pr_name = "";        
                pr_text.setText("");
                }
         repaint();
             // The user's input from the text area.                     
            int pr_char;

           String array[]=pr_name.split(" ");
           int counter=0;
           for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
               if(counter<array[i].length())
                   counter=array[i].length();
           int intArray[]=new int[counter];
           for(int i=0;i<intArray.length;i++){
               intArray[i]=0;
           }
           for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
               intArray[array[i].length()-1]++;
           }
           String a="";
           for(int i=0;i<intArray.length;i++){
               if(intArray[i]>0)
               {
                a+=String.valueOf(intArray[i]);
                a+=", ";
               }
           }
           pr_label.setText(a);


           pr_char = pr_name.length(); 
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
  //      g.setColor(pr_col);
     //   g.drawString(pr_name,0,250);
      pr_text.setSize(400, 200);
      pr_text.setLocation(0,0);
      pr_input1.setLocation(150,220);
      pr_input2.setLocation(200,220);
      pr_label.setLocation(0,270);
      pr_label.setSize(400,30);
    }
}
```

---

The spaces aren't a problem as the code doesn't include them anyway, I only looks for words. the problem im having now is when I put the code where ive been told in doesn't give me the correct pattern and jut limits it to 1. ie I am a man comes out with 1, instead of 2, 1, 1,

Comment: Apply the line your lecturer gave to `pr_name` before you split into words.

Comment: @rsp: That would make splitting very hard, wouldn't it?

Comment: "also on a side note i haven't actually been taught str.replace yet." should you wait to be taught?

Comment: What will your input look like? What kind of delimiters can you expect?

Comment: @Keppil, not when you add a space character to the character set in the regexp, something I wouldn't put beyond a student at a university.

Comment: @rsp: Well, a `You will have to modify it slightly` or something similar would have been helpful in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Replace all instances of `array[i].length()` with the variable `length` in your loop after you define `length` as:

```
int length = array[i].replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "").length();
```

Replace:

```
       for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
           if(counter<array[i].length())
               counter=array[i].length();
```

With:

```
       for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
           int length = array[i].replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "").length();
           if(counter<length)
               counter=length;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of **Regular Expressions**.  The first string in the **replaceAll** call defines the pattern of what it's looking for.

In this case, the "^" character means "not" and "A-Za-z" means all uppercase and lowercase letters.  So the overall pattern means, anything that's not a letter. That's the wrong pattern if you want to split on spaces, so you also have to add "\s" to include whitespace characters. Thus, the call:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z\s]", "")
```

Will replace anything that's not a letter or a whitespace character with an empty string.

In your program, you would insert this call before you do your string processing. Like this:

```
pr_name = pr_name.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z\s]", "")
String array[]=pr_name.split(" ");
```

Comment: This would remove all of the spaces.

Comment: Oh, yes it would. Sorry, just took his original pattern. I'll fix that.

Comment: I would argue that this answer would require insight into how regex works, which the original poster doesn't seem to have.

Comment: That's not an unreasonable point, but it really only requires knowledge of regex if he needs to further alter the pattern. Given that he was already trying to use **String.replaceAll** anyway, on the advice of his teacher, no less, adding the whitespace code to the pattern isn't making a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
   intArray[array[i].length()-1]++;
}
```

with

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
   intArray[array[i].replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "").length()-1]++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Place your instructor's suggestion above this:

```
String array[]=pr_name.split(" ");
```

It appears you're storing the text string as pr_name so before you split on the spaces, you can strip the other characters.  It should appear like this:

```
pr_name = pr_name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\s:]", "");
String array[]=pr_name.split(" ");
```

Comment: As I commented above, you can't remove all spaces (and other non-letters) and then split on space.

Comment: This would remove all of the spaces.

Comment: So change the regex to make it work.  I edited above and also ignore spaces.  Don't hurry to down-vote as the question was how to incorporate the professor's code and where I instructed to use the professor's code is correct.  Professor was wrong with the regex, but could add the \s to it and then it will ignore alpha and spaces.  If you also wanted to include numbers as protected, then add \d like this:  [^a-zA-Z\d\s:]